# Django Count how many manytomany relation ships in an attribute

Tags: django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

This is my model:

```
class Set(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 25)
    teacher = ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    students = ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name= 'set_students')
```

and I want to know how many students are in the manytomanyfield.

Ive tried this

```
set_ = Set.objects.get(pk=id_)
students = len(set_.students)
```

But that hasn't worked.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use queryset's method [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) directly on students field: `set_.students.count()`.